# Write a file on a different server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

So I'm trying to write a file on a different server while trying to access it using url.

```
_config.Value.ImagesPath = "http://this.com/where/the/file/is"
```

```
var filePath2 = _config.Value.ImagesPath + pdfName;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, file);
```

When I launch it locally, everything is fine and the file is created, but the moment I use IIS it doesn't work I don't know why it took the physical path and concatenated it with the uri knowing that it doesn't do when I launch it locally

```
2022-11-22 11:56:27.3963 ERROR Some error in the PushFiles method: System.IO.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte : 'E:\Application\RAS\PA_RAS_G22\Build\where\the\file\is\http://this.com\where\the\file\is'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
```

I tried to debug to see if the path is generated correctly which is the case, and when I do it the file is correctly created. It's just when I publish to IIS that It doesn't work

Comment: That's not a file path, that's a URL. The error says that this isn't a correct file path, because it's not a file path at all. You can't upload files to web sites using file commands

Comment: `When I launch it locally, everything is fine and the file is created` I seriously doubt that. The error would be exactly the same whether you used IIS or not. `E:\Application\RAS\PA_RAS_G22\Build\where\the\file\is\http://this.com\where\the\file\is` is invalid whether you run your code in VS or in production. You must have used different paths

Comment: Are you trying to save a file on a shared folder? The path syntax is `\\servername\sharedfoler\path\to\file.pdf`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well the URL take you to the folder to the other server where the file should be written, is there a way to take a url and transform it to a path so i can write a file there ?

Comment: No it doesn't. A URL may not even correspond to a real path, especially in ASP.NET Core where URLs map to controllers and actions. Perhaps you have a *file URL* that points to a file server path? Why not use the actual path?

Comment: Where are you trying to save that file? A shared folder? Network storage that runs Linux? Upload it to a remote server? The first two can be done using the correct path. Even a Linux NAS will run an Samba server so you can use `\\server\folder\...`. If you have an `https://` URL it's no different than trying to upload an image to some other web server - it just can't be done with file commands. You'll have to POST that file to the web server using eg HttpClient.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's a remote server which its main purpose is to store files, at first I thought that instead of using 
 - http: \\servername\sharedfoler\path\to\file.pdf
I should use 
- file:\\servername\sharedfoler\path\to\file.pdf

But now what i understood it's not the case

Comment: Besides, the *error* shows that `pdfName` is a full URL and `_config.Value.ImagesPath` is `E:\Application\RAS\PA_RAS_G22\Build\where\the\file\is\`. That's very different from what you asked. You're trying to save locally and need the file name part. If you retrieve that file with HttpClient, the file name is probably in the `Content-Disposition` header. If you can't access that you can extract the last part from the URL through the [Segments property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-7.0). The filename will be the last item.

Comment: Those are path names, not URLs. The actual *full* path name is `\\servername\sharedfoler\path\to\file.pdf` without any prefix. On Linux it would use slashes instead of backslashes. In no case would it have a prefix. Linux IO commands don't understand URLs either

Comment: A file *URL* would have the form `file://server/filename.ext`. You can translate that to a local path with [Uri.LocalPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.localpath?view=net-7.0). On Windows `LocalPath` would return `\\server\filename.ext`. If you pass a non-file URL, eg `https://www.google.com/filename.ext` though, you'll get back `/filename.ext`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually pdfName is just the name of the pdf and _config.Value.ImagesPath is : http:\\serverhost`where\the\file\is so if concact them both it's http:\\serverhost`where\the\file\is\pdfname.pdf

Comment: The error message says otherwise. It says that `ImagePath` is `E:\Application\RAS\PA_RAS_G22\Build\where\the\file\is` and that `pdfName` is `http://this.com\where\the\file\is`. The error path starts with `E:....` and ends with `https....`. In general, instead of concatenating strings use `Path.Combine` to take care of any trailing backslashes. That wouldn't help here though

Comment: Well that's exactly what I don't understand, I'm pretty sure that pdfName is just I name that I made so that I can name the pdf when I'm debugging I can see that

 var filePath2 = _config.Value.ImagesPath + pdfName; 
file path2 = http://this.com\where\the\file\is\pdfname.pdf